# Pointers and String manipulation

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm writing a function/method in C that is supposed to do the following:

> /**  * Recieves the list of arguments and copies to conffile the name
>   of  * the configuration file.  * Returns 1 if the default file name
>   was used or 2 if  * the parameter -f existed and therefor the
>   specified name was used. Returns 0 if there is a -f     * parameter
>   but is invalid. (last argument)
>   */

Basically one of these two option will be "asked" by the program:

1- controller -f   FCFS|LOOK

2- controller  FCFS|LOOK

If the second is asked, we enter the case of using the default name.

```
 int get_conf_name(char* argv[], char* conffile) { 

// Searches for -f 

 s = strstr(*argv, "-f");


if(s != NULL){

      if(//its valid){
 strcpy(conffile, //the name of the file which comes after -f

 return 2

 }

      else return 0

 }

 else{

 strcpy(confile, "config.vss")

 return 1

 }

 }
```

The problem here is how do I get the word after -f and copy it to confile? And, can I access argv the same way I access conffile, since one of them is an array?
I thought of using a for loop and a strlen, but that would be a lot of unecessary work for the computer wouldn't it?

Comment: That's not how `strstr` works. `strstr` looks for a substring (needle) in another string (haystack). What you want instead is looking for a whole string in an array of strings. You should use a loop.

Comment: btw: options are "passed to" (not "asked by") the program. Unless you're referring to the caller program.

Comment: @Giulio Franco Oh thanks :D By asked I meant there's two possible options for the user to ask the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the assignment expects you to go through the individual arguments one by one, comparing them to `"-f"`.

- If you see no `-f`, you know that the default file needs to be used
- If you see the flag in the final position, you know that the `-f` is invalid
- If you see the flag in the position `k`, then the file name will be in `argv[k+1]`

The skeleton of your program should look like this:

```
bool foundFlag = false;
for (int i = 1 ; i < argc ; i++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-f") == 0) {
        if (i == argc-1) {
            // Error
        } else {
            // argv[i+1] is the file name;
        }
        foundFlag = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!foundFlag) {
    // Default name is used
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the skeleton is very clean and understandable :D So now, I can use argv[i+1] directly on strcpy right? But won't that [i+1] point to the space instead of the first char of the name?

Comment: @ipg24 That's the thing - spaces and tabs are taken out of the original command string when it is tokenized. Only non-whitespace characters are kept.

Comment: Understood :) Thanks a lot, now I know how to structure and write the whole thing!